SULU frontend with twig and react
I'm working on a SULU project that uses Twig for the frontend and has a custom webpack for it. I need to use React for certain components, components that require more interaction, state management, etc. How can I do that actually? How can I adapt my webpack to both twig components and the react part I want to add?
const webpack = require("webpack");
const date = new Date();
const ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new ESLintPlugin({
                emitWarning: true,
                failOnError: true,
            }),

            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                BUILD: JSON.stringify(
                    `BUILD: ${date.getDate()}.${
                        date.getMonth() + 1
                    }.${date.getHours()}.${date.getMinutes()}`
                ),
            }),
        ],
    };
};

I tried this, but it seems like its not working:
module.exports = () => {
    return {
        mode:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                ? "production"
                : "development",
        entry: "./js/main.js",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public/build/website/js"),
            filename: "main.js",
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                "@babel/preset-react",
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.module\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName:
                                        "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        "sass-loader",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        },
        plugins: [
            new ESLintPlugin({
                emitWarning: true,
                failOnError: true,
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                BUILD: JSON.stringify(
                    `${new Date().getDate()}.${
                        new Date().getMonth() + 1
                    }.${new Date().getHours()}.${new Date().getMinutes()}`
                ),
            }),
        ],
    };
};


Sulu let you use the frontend tools you want and doesn't force you what to use. This also means there are lot of different possibilities to achieve things.
If you are using symfony / twig you might use webpack encore to build your CSS / JS. There it should also be possible to enable react support with a few lines, see the official Symfony Documentation about this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/reactjs.html
You also find step by step Tutorials to this topic in SymfonyCasts:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/reactjs
Webpack Encore is a layer around Webpack to make configuration of such things easier. You might can replace your current webpack setup with webpack encore https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html. It can be used without stimulus or hotwire which I do myself.
